# javascript variable -chrome transition

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables, cross-browser

if i put the value to be passed in `translateX()` function in a variable `pos` (see the code below) , the transition effect is not shown in chrome but works fine in Firefox, whereas by giving the value directly in `translateX()` function, it works in both.

```
  //javascript::
<script>
   function fn()
 {
        var pos=100;        //variable pos defines position of text
        var idd="one";
        var elem=document.getElementById(idd);


     /*does not work in chrome*/   elem.style.cssText="transition:transform 1s;-webkit-transition:transform 1s;transform:translateX("+pos+"px);-webkit-transform:translateX("+pos+"px);"; 

/* works in both           elem.style.cssText="transition:transform 1s;-webkit-transition:transform 1s;transform:translateX(100px);-webkit-transform:translateX(100px);";*/     
 }
</script>
//html ::
<body>

   <div  id="one" >
    text
   </div>

   <div onclick="fn()">
    click
   </div>
 </body>
```